# How to change default font?

Tags: fonts

Sometimes even I change the text font from arial to courier new, when a new formula cell is created, things inside become arial again. How to tackle this problem? Furthermore, is it possible to change the default font?

Comment: @jason The standard way would be to edit the StyleSheet. Is it the option in your case?

Comment: Can you briefly describe what should I do?

Comment: @Jason, This question has been discussed several times, though I cannot give a reference off hand. However, few years ago David Park published at http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive a notebook containing a nice step-by-step instruction. Again unfortunately I have no exact reference. I have the notebook though and can send it you privately. I doubt that it is eligible to publish it, however. If I am wrong, I ask more experienced people to correct me. Then I will publish it.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html